# One domain for multiple self-hosted services VS a single domain per service?

Tags: onion-services, bandwidth, web-hosting, performance, onionaddress

After generating a self-signed SSL certificate for a self-hosted Dash app, and verifying that it is accessible over tor, I intend to include self-hosted GitLab and Nextcloud over https. Hence, I was wondering whether there are any advantages/disadvantages for creating either:

- 1 onion domain per service?
- 1 domain with all services on different ports?

I thought that perhaps 1 domain per service might be a bit more secure, because if one domain is somehow compromised (by me not setting something up securely), it would perhaps have a lower probability of also compromising the other services. However, my main concern is not with security, but with performance.

- Is there a difference in performance between the two situations (bandwidth and/or latency wise)?
- Is the load I put on the onion network different for the two situations?

Comment: I don't know about the performance, but I wouldn't worry about putting extra load on the network. Running a couple of onion services would be fine, but if you were running a large number then it would be worth considering.